# Null pointer exception thrown when creating a Double to test null check

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

This may be a stupid question, but I have a method that will convert Doubles or BigDecimals to a formatted String:

```
//There is also a method that accepts BigDecimals
public String convertToCurrencyString(Double aAmount) {
    if(aAmount == null){
        return "$0.00";
    }
    NumberFormat numFormat = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    numFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    String amount = numFormat.format(aAmount);
    return amount;
}
```

I'm currently trying to test this method with JUnit by instantiating a Double:

```
Double nullDouble = new Double(null);
```

The problem is a NullPointerException is being thrown when the creating the Double. Is there a way to stop this happening, or is this normal behaviour? The need for the null check is that there are some older records in a database that have these Doubles and BigDecimals set to null

Comment: `Double nullDouble = null`?

Comment: as I suspected, it was a stupid question. Just out of curiosity, Why would my initial Double throw a null pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Double(null)` calls the `Double(String)` constructor, which tries to parse the given string into a double. But with a `null` String it fails with a NullPointerException.

The proper way to pass a null Double to your method is to simply call:

```
String resultForNull = convertToCurrencyString(null);
```

Also since your method does not use the enclosing class' state, it may make sense to make it `static`.